# Google location auto complete is not working on aws server

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am using google location autocomplete at aws server its not working and the same code i am using on another server its working fine you can check here AWS==> http://52.91.226.167/testgeo.php other server==>http://142.4.10.93/~vooap/alcohol/test.php geocomplete needs any server side setting ?

Comment: Do you use a Google Maps API key? If so, it may be restricted on some domain only.

Comment: Yes but i was using it without key also it was working for me at my old server but on aws nothing is working

Comment: Do you see any error in browser console?

Comment: no i don't see any error i have provided links in my question please check these  i wonder when i hit ==>http://52.91.226.167/testgeo.php it is not showing location but when i hit http://142.4.10.93/~vooap/alcohol/test.php  which is working fine after that i hit the first link then it is giving me the output

Comment: in fact I see an error message when hiting the autocomplete in 52.91.226.167 saying: "This service requires an API key.  For more information on authentication and Google Maps Javascript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key". I guess Google uses some IP filters in their API.

Comment: Yes this is warning and you can check in other link console same warning is there but its working fine

Comment: No it's not the same message. For the working one, when the autocomplete query is sent, there is no error message. You receive correctly the response. Look in network panel, not in console.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a valid API key as mentionned in the message received when the autocomplete message is sent:

[image: ajax error message]

You can see this message under Network panel in developer console. Each time you hit a key in the input, an ajax request is sent and you receive this message.